# MySQLi Query Does not working | Blank PHP Page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am learning PHP. I am trying one simple mysqli query. I have checked query manually in phpmyadmin and its working fine but in PHP page its not responding. Its not giving any error to. Its appear just blank page. I have checked my db connection and its working fine. I do not know what is issue in it. let me know if anyone can help me for solve it.
My full PHP file is like below

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include_once("includes/connection.php");
    $input = "hello";
    $sql = "SELECT answer FROM faq WHERE question = 'hello' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    if ($result !== false) {
        $value = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
        echo $value;
    } else {
        echo "errors";
    }
?>
```

My connection file is like below

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
    DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); //host name depends on server
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'test');

    $mysqli =mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8mb4");
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");     
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: If connection is working then check query again, if this query really fetching any data for you.

Comment: Try echo "Value => ".$value; instead of echo $value; It will be able to detect the blank value, if any.

Comment: @ChintanThummar its still blank page

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh.....I have double checked and its working fine in phpmyadmin

Comment: check if the condition comes to if {} or else{} by puting exit; within if and else on the start like echo 'test'; exit; and echo 'test1' exit; Or you can add die() in query to check

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) `mysqli_fetch_field()` will return an object. You can't `echo()` an Object. But you can print the result like

```
while ($finfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {

    printf("Name:     %s\n", $finfo->name);
    printf("Table:    %s\n", $finfo->table);
    printf("max. Len: %d\n", $finfo->max_length);
    printf("Flags:    %d\n", $finfo->flags);
    printf("Type:     %d\n\n", $finfo->type);
}
```

Comment: pos worth noting you can echo object properties, e.g. `echo $info->name`

Comment: @treyBake yes, I know. I just copied the code from an example from the manual. Thought it would be better than just echoing everything

Answer (score 0):

enable error reporting in PHP as:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will show the error list on page.

Comment: although I agree with the ini_set idea - it's not directly an answer to the issue and better suited as a comment. I know you don't have enough rep to comment but it's best to wait til you can answer a question with 100% certainty to gain enough rep to start commenting.